# SQL Server 2008: What is a sanity Check?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I came across a "Sanity Check" sql task in an old DTS Package, but I cannot open it to look at the code because of some error.

I was just wondering what a sanity check is and how to write one.

thanks

Comment: Ha Ha! I would have thought that this will do a superficial check of some condition that the data looks reasonably "sane" and the DTS task can proceed. Can you export the DTS package to VB and read it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a sanity check is some beyond error condition, like

```
if 1+1 !=2
BEGIN
   PRINT 'the sky is falling!!!'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

*I was just wondering what a sanity check is...*

Straight [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_testing):

> A sanity test or sanity check is a
>   basic test to quickly evaluate whether
>   a claim or the result of a calculation
>   can possibly be true. The point of a
>   sanity test is to rule out certain
>   classes of obviously false results,
>   not to catch every possible error. In
>   arithmetic, for example, when
>   multiplying by 9, using the
>   divisibility rule for 9 to verify that
>   the sum of digits of the result is
>   divisible by 9 is a sanity test - it
>   will not catch every multiplication
>   error, however it's a quick and simple
>   method to discover many possible
>   errors.
>
> In computer science, a sanity
>   test is a very brief run-through of
>   the functionality of a computer
>   program, system, calculation, or other
>   analysis, to assure that the system or
>   methodology works as expected, often
>   prior to a more exhaustive round of
>   testing.

*... and how to write one.*

Apply the above.

Comment: there is no call for rudeness, that really hurt my feelings

Comment: @Matt: I didn't mean to be rude, I felt like I answered the question ?